# How many descending sequences are there in an array

Tags: java, arrays

My method should return the number of descending sequences in an array. If the next number, in an array, is greater than the previous one then it is a start of a new sequence. Could someone guide/explain me what's wrong with the my code?

```
public static int countDescents(int[] xs) {

      int descents = 0;
      int i = 0;
      for(i = 0; i < xs.length; i++)
      {
          for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            descents++;

      }
    return descents;
  }
```

Comment: What's wrong is that your code does not test the `xs` array contents, so it is unable to detect any ascending or descending sequences at all.

Comment: Can you please put in a bit more clarification ?

Comment: Let's say an array is {4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3}---> this array has 3 sequnces (1st is from 4-7, 2d is from 1-4, and 3d from 1-3)

Comment: CiaPan, why do you think it does not test the xs array ?

Comment: Because I can't see any expression in the code using `xs` identifier. The array is declared as an input data for the function but not referenced anywhere later (except reading `xs.length`, which depends on the number of items but not on their values, so has nothing to do with any 'sequences').

Comment: In an array like  {4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3} a sequnce 4-7 is **ascending**, not descending, There are only two descending sequences here: 7–1 and 4–1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it should work :

```
public static int countDescents(int[] xs) {

  int descents = 0;
  boolean onAscendingSequence = true
  int i = 0;

  // we traverse the list, from the second element
  for(i = 1; i < xs.length; i++) {
      // ascending sequence TO descending sequence
      if (onAscendingSequence && xs[i] < xs[i-1]) {
        descents++;
        onAscendingSequence = false;

      // descending sequence TO ascending sequence
      } else if (!onAscendingSequence && xs[i] > xs[i-1]) {
        onAscendingSequence = true;
      }

  }
  return descents;
}
```

Comment: The answer is right but could you explain this part:if (onSequence && xs[i] < xs[i-1]) {
        descents++;
        onSequence = false;
      } else if (!onSequence && xs[i] > xs[i-1]) {
        onSequence = true;
      }